# How to prevent multiple dots in js calculator and how to convert number to its opposite value

Tags: javascript, html, decimal, calculator

I am making a JS calculator and I have only problem with two stages of my code.

first one is when I'm trying to switch the sign

```
 else if (textbox.value == "+/-") {
                textbox.value = -Math.sign(textbox.value) * textbox.value
        }
```

and also when I'm adding a dot to the equation it gets added multiple times as seen below

```
else if (!String(textbox.value).includes(".") && textbox.value != "") {
                textbox.value += "."
            }
```

These two codes are not working properly.I would be glad if you helped.Here is full code if you need:

```js
        var nums = document.getElementById("num")
        var operator = document.getElementById("ope")
        var textbox = document.getElementById("txtBox")
        var counter = 0

        function Click(e) {
            var but = e.target;
            var maxamount = 9;
            var dot = 1
            if (but.innerText != "=" && but.innerText != "delete") {
                textbox.value += but.innerText
                if (but.innerText == "C") {
                    textbox.value = "0"
                }
                else if (textbox.value[0] == "." || textbox.value[0] == "0" || textbox.value[0] == "+" || textbox.value[0] == "-" || textbox.value[0] == "/" || textbox.value[0] == "*") {
                    textbox.value = ""
                }
                else if (textbox.value.length > maxamount) {
                    textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, maxamount)
                }
                else if (!String(textbox.value).includes(".") && textbox.value != "") {
                    textbox.value += "."
                }
            }

            else {
                textbox.value = eval(textbox.value)
            }
            if (but.innerText == "delete") {
                textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, textbox.value.length - 1);
            }
            else if (textbox.value == "NaN" || textbox.value == "undefine") {
                textbox.value = ""
            }
            else if (textbox.value == "+/-") {
                textbox.value = -Math.sign(textbox.value) * textbox.value
            }
        }
```

```css
            button {
                user-select: none; 
                font-size:23px; 
                width:80px ; 
                height: 70px; 
                font-family:bold;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border-color: gray;
            }
            .ope{
                background: rgb(96, 250, 199);
            }
            .num:focus {
                background: lime;
            }
```

```html
    <input id="txtBox" type="text" style="text-align: right;font-size:60px;width: 325px;height: 125px; font-family: bold;" />
    <br />
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">C</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">delete</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">+/-</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">+</button>

    <br />

    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">1</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">2</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">3</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">-</button>

    <br />

    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">4</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">5</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">6</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">*</button>

    <br />

    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">7</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">8</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">9</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="ope">/</button>

    <br />

    <button onclick="Click(event)" class="num">0</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" id="ope">.</button>
    <button onclick="Click(event)" id="equalto" style="background: rgb(206, 37, 206);user-select: none;font-size:25px; width:160px ; height: 70px; font-family:bold;">=</button>
```

Comment: What is wrong with them?  What are they supposed to be doing, and what are they actually doing?  "It doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: @Amy first code must change the value to opposite while onclick it does completely nothing.Second code  must let "." to output only once and no more than that while it output dot right after one of the numbers is clicked.Yeah situation like this.I can't understand what is wrong with my code

Comment: To change a number to "its opposite", just multiply by -1.

Comment: If the textbox value is `"+/-"`, how do you intend to multiply by `"+/-"` inside the IF block?  How do you intend `Math.sign("+/-")` to get the sign of a number? 
 It isn't a number.

Comment: @Amy it is the easiest way and I already tried it.But it just outputs "+/-" itself. Math.sign can be wrong,because I only found it on internet.But multiplying to -1 isn't working

Comment: That's because you aren't multiplying a number by -1.  You are multiplying the string `"+/-"` by -1.  How is that supposed to work?  It isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

**swapping between negative/positive numbers, multiply by -1, and make sure to specify that the button is +/- button**

```
else if (textbox.value == "+/-") {
  textbox.value *= -1
}
```

**adding a dot needs three rules**

a- if there's no dot yet

b- if the string isn't empty

c- if the clicked button is the dot button

```
else if (!textbox.value.includes('.') && but.innerText === '.' && textbox.value.length) {
  textbox.value += "."
}
```

Comment: thanks for sparing your time to answer,but none of this variants just don't work out for my code.I have tried your codes too,I have no idea why non of theese works

Comment: If the textbox value is `"+/-"`, then it isn't a number.  You can't multiply a string by -1, let alone a non-numeric string.